# loosing data of Fragments on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a list fragment and a details fragment. when item is selected on list fragment corresponding data will be changed in details fragment. I have lot of initilizations on onCreate of main activity which controls this fragments. I dont want to recreate all this data on change of orientation... is it possible. also my data that was entered manually in all details fragment will be lost whenever orientaton is changed.. please suggest how to retain the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add single line in your manifest file**

```
<activity
            android:name="com.abc.src.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
 />
```

**UPDATE**

*override this method in your main activity from where you managing fragments.*

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            // set visibility visible of Layout in which your list fragment resides 
        }else if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            // set visibility gone of Layout in which your list fragment resides
        }
    }
```

Comment: incase if i want to show only details fragmnet and not the list fragment on orientation change.... we generlly do this coniditonal check in oncreate...so this will impact now rite ?? i mean oncreate wll not be called in this case to chage the view